# pointer returns zero even though it has been assigned a non zero pointer

Tags: c++

I have this function that should assigne a pointer to another pointer but the pointer returns a zero.

```
void setLeftChild(TreeNode* child){
    leftChild = unique_ptr<TreeNode>(child);
    parent = this;}
```

I tried printing 'this' which has a valid pointer in it. I also tried to print the parent's value and it also is a valid pointer. But for some reason after the method is called parent has a value of zero. I have a constructor which sets parent to nullptr that explains the zero but doesnt explain why it remains a zero. parent is a pointer to a TreeNode.

EDIT 1: some code was not needed so removed it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post the whole code meaning the whole class definition or every method were your modify parent. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Where is `parent` declared?

Comment: I'd be very concerned with passing a raw pointer into a setter and ownership of it taken by a `unique_ptr`. Your interface doesn't indicate that ownership will be taken.

Comment: _"... after the method is called ..."_ but you don't show the call site. _"I have a constructor which ..."_ you also haven't shown. Without that minimum reproducible example, no-one can do much but guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ is implicitly referenceing this->parent, and as a result, is setting your current node's parent variable to itself. You need to specify `leftChild->parent` or `child->parent` in order to assign the pointer properly.

```cpp
void setLeftChild(TreeNode* child){
    leftChild = unique_ptr<TreeNode>(child);
    parent = this;}
//  ^^^^^^ 
//  C++ is implicitly referencing this->parent,
//  since you never specified leftChild or child
```